# Refreshing a Div After AJAX Success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

There's a lot of Stack Overflow questions on this topic, but none seem to work for me.

This may be due to the fact that I need a PHP function called when the `div` is refreshed in order for the information to be updated.

I have a `#tab-project-CD-smt_test` div that shows three versions (production, staging, and latest). The user can click an arrow next to the staging or latest to move it up the chain.  I have this part working fine through the use of an AJAX request:

```
    function sendToStaging (dir, type, subtype, version) {
        //Need selected category, selected type, selected subtype 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'configs.php',
            data: 'function=sendToStaging'+'&dir='+dir+'&type='+type+'&subtype='+subtype+'&version='+version, 
            success: function() {
//                 window.location.reload(true);
                $('#deployed').load(document.URL);
            }
        });

    };

    function sendToProduction (dir, type, subtype, version) {
        //Need selected category, selected type, selected subtype 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'configs.php',
            data: 'function=sendToProduction'+'&dir='+dir+'&type='+type+'&subtype='+subtype+'&version='+version
        });
```

On success, I would like to refresh the `#deployed` div, which is created in my PHP `makeInfoSection`. An excerpt of which is below:

```
// list latest, staging, production
$html .= '<h4>Deployed Versions</h4>';
$html .= '<ul class="list-group" id="deployed">';

$html .= '<li class="list-group-item">';
$html .= '<span class="badge">production</span>';
$html .= $production.'</li>';

$html .= '<li class="list-group-item">';
$html .= '<span class="badge"><a href="#" style="color:orange"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sendToProduction('."'$dir', '$type', '$subType', '$staging'".')"></span></a></span>';


$html .= '<span class="badge">staging</span>';
$html .= $staging.'</li>';

$html .= '<li class="list-group-item">';
$html .= '<span class="badge"><a href="#" style="color:orange"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" onclick="sendToStaging('."'$dir', '$type', '$subType', '$latest'".')"></span></a></span>';



$html .= '<span class="badge">latest</span>';
$html .= $latest.'</li>';
$html .= '</ul>';
```

The method is called in the HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-push-1 col-sm-6">
        <div id="tabs" class="tab-content" style="padding:0em 0em 0em 1em">
            <?php
                foreach ($project_types as $type) {
                    // @TODO remove once folder structure is all setup
                    if ($type !== 'CD') continue;

                    foreach ($project_subtypes[$type] as $subType) {
                        $html = "<div role ='tabpanel' class='tab-pane'";
                        $html .= "id='tab-project-".$type."-".$subType."'>";
                        $html .= makeInfoSection($type, $subType, $project_versions[$subType], $project_dir);
                        $html .= "</div>";
                        echo $html;
                    }
                }

                foreach ($workflow_types as $type) {
                    foreach ($workflow_subtypes[$type] as $subType) {
                        $html = "<div role ='tabpanel' class='tab-pane'";
                        $html .= "id='tab-workflow-".$type."-".$subType."'>";
                        $html .= makeInfoSection($type, $subType, $workflow_versions[$subType], $workflow_dir);
                        $html .= "</div>";
                        echo $html;
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So upon the success of the AJAX, I need this to be refreshed.  I've tried `$('#tab-project-CD-smt_test').load(document.URL);` but that doesn't seem to do anything.  I've also tried calling the `makeInfoSection` method but that does not add it to the HTML, so I'm not surprised that it didn't work:

```
$approved_functions = array('sendToProduction', 'sendToLatest', 'sendToStaging');
if(array_key_exists('function', $_POST) && in_array($_POST['function'], $approved_functions)) {
    // call the approved function
    $dir = $_POST['dir']; 
    $type =  $_POST['type']; 
    $subType = $_POST['subtype']; 
    $version = $_POST['version']; 
    $_POST['function']($dir, $type, $subType, $version);
    makeInfoSection($type, $subType, $versions, $dir); 
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this `div` to refresh?

Comment: One issue I see is that you will have the same `id` `deployed` at least twice in your HTML. The `makeInfoSection` function has `id='deployed'` hard coded into it. This will be a problem when you are attempting to update a specific div because `id`s are supposed to be unique.

Comment: AJAX loading of the current page you are on to get some PHP rendered HTML is fairly common. I think you are close with the [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function, but when you call it, I believe it tries to load the whole page. Per its documentation, you can try `$('#deployed').load(document.URL + ' #deployed');` This should only take the `#deployed` div and overwrite the innerHTML for your current `#deployed` div in your DOM.

Comment: @Keeleon, that's true it is used multiple times. It's under the div `#tab-project-CD-smt_test`. So I suppose I would want to refresh that div.

Comment: @tibsar That would work, yes. It's acting as a parent (container) div to your `deployed` div anyway. Consider using a class for your deployed divs instead.

Comment: @romellem Please add your comment as an answer, with a bit more detail and sample code, so OP can accept as answer (or at least upvote)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@tibsar, you mentioned that `#deployed` isn't unique across your page. [While you should try to avoid this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127180/146296), to answer your question, you mentioned that `#tab-project-CD-smt_test` *is* unique, so ajax loading that should work for you.

If you'd like to use [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), try this in your `success` callback:

```
$('#tab-project-CD-smt_test').load(document.URL + ' #tab-project-CD-smt_test');
```

Let us know if that works.

Comment: I use your answer but when load the div id or class automatically add another same div . so can you help me for this?

Comment: hey @H_Parekh check this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58165233/646922